# How to convert m3u8 streaming video to mp4

Tags: ios, swift3, video-streaming

Is there any way to convert streaming m3u8 file to mp4.
and save the mp4 file to Gallery in Swift 3.0.

I have tried the below code,

```
func setupAssetDownload(url:URL) {
        //
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "streamVideo")
        let downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                                        assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let downloadTask = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                                 assetTitle: "",
                                                                 assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                                 options: nil)
            downloadTask?.resume()
    }
```

suddenly is calling the finish downloading.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
}
```

Then, Can I get the entire streaming session and save to gallery when press on the stop action.